# shift left with 1's behind? C language

Tags: c, binary, shift

i would like to know if this is possible...

I know that 255 = 11111111 and if i do 255 << pos*8 with pos=1 i will have 1111111100000000.

I would like to know if is possible to get the value 1111111111111111 with shift left without
doing a cicle while or for.

Thanks.

Comment: No you cannot do this with a left-shift alone.  I can't tell you what the solution is, though, because you haven't explained what the general rule is.  What if the input is something different, like `10011010`?

Comment: To get "the value 1111111111111111 with shift left without doing a cicle while or for": `0xFFFF << 0`.  But like @Oli says, need more info to create a general rule.

Answer (score 5):

```
int output = (input << shift) | ((1 << shift) - 1);
```

Comment: `((input + 1) << shift) - 1` is possibly equivalent with this. In case OP doesn't feel alright with usage of `|`, kek

Comment: @DRS Because you have typed it wrong? `(val << (pos * 8)) | ((1 << (pos * 8)) - 1)` with `val=255` and `pos=1` gives the result you asked for in your question which is `65535` aka `1111111111111111`. This answer is correct.